# Circuit understanding

Tags: electricity

I have a few questions regarding my understanding of circuits.

When you hook a battery up to a conductor does the chemical reactions which take place create a difference in charge between the terminals?

If so, is it the electric field created by this difference which exerts a force on charge placed in the circuit?

I know a 9V battery means a unit positive charge would deliver 9J of energy  if it were to travel between the terminals (from positive to negative), but does the size of the voltage affect the magnitude of the force exerted on the charges?

If this is right, is this why an increase in voltage increases current but also means a unit positive charge as it travels around the circuit can deliver more energy as it reaches a higher KE between collisions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fairly close...

- The chemical reactions in the battery create a difference in potential between the two terminals, whether there's a conductor hooked up or not. Connect the conductor, and that potential pushes charge through it (allowing the chemical reactions to proceed faster, like a fire when you allow air in freely)
- Exactly : that potential difference creates the electric field which exerts force on the charge.
- Again, correct : that unit of charge ( = 1 Coulomb = 1 amp for 1 second) carries 9J from 9V, or 18J from 18V.
- Correct twice again : unless the conductor's resistance R changes, twice the voltage pushes twice the current; AND each Coulomb carries twice the energy. This means 4x the power; which is expressed as P = V^2/R.

(Note that the conductor's resistance may change : in a lampbulb it increases as the wire heats up, so the current won't double; it may also become infinite if the conductor is a fuse!)

Comment: Thanks, does the difference in potential come about due to a difference in charge?

Comment: That might be arguing semantics, but I'd say no, it comes from the chemistry (the electro-negativities of the metals in the battery) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronegativity